# Create a plugin for the Admin Dashboard in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on creating a plugin that will be used by WordPress admins. the plugin will allow users to create a specific kind of user so I will be creating pages similar to account creation forms. My questions are:

1- When i create this plugin and since it will only be used by administrators should I place the folder/files for this plugin in the wp-admin folder or in the wp-content/plugins folder?

2- When i create this plugin am i able to use the functionality of other plugins? For example, i have a plugin that allows me to create forms.. Can i use this plugin to create this form and then in my plugin use/reference the created form?

Comment: 1) Plugins have to be placed in the `/wp-content/plugins` folder (or in `/wp-content/mu-plugins` if yours is a [MU plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/)); 2) It depends on how you plan to integrate other plugins' functionalities into yours. If you haven't done so yet, it might be a good idea to review the official documentation to learn more on how WordPress plugins work: [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/).

Comment: For #2 - you should check that the other plugins are available during activation. I use [register_activation_hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/).